# iframe not disappearing

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

I have an iframe:

```
parent.document.getElementById("IFRAMENAME").style.display = "none";
```

What would cause this code not to work?  If i set the width to 0px it hides it.  I debugged to make sure all the values of the frame are coming back.

I am using ie 7

Answer (score 1):

IFRAMENAME suggests you use the name of the IFrame. That is not right. You should use the id as specified in the id attribute.

```
<iframe name="notthisone" id="butthisone" src="whatever.htm"></iframe>
```

Comment: Well, he said that setting the width did succeed. So it's probably not a name/id conflict...

Answer (score 1):

Is your stylesheet overriding this assignment?

If you have:

```
 iframe#IFRAMENAME {display:block !important}
```

or something similar, it could supercede that code.

Also, does the code work in, say, other browsers?

Comment: It should not override any css in the stylesheet. Part of CSS is the order in which styles apply. This order dictates that styles on the element itself always take precedense.